# Android Tabwidget change Textview color programatically

Tags: android-tabhost

In below tabview layout contents how to get reference for each textview and change color, text programatically.?

For example i want to change RF1235678 textview color and text

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vishwanath

```
TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("exampletab");
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
tab1.setIndicator(textView);

tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

Comment: In fact, you can fully customize your texview.